# ArrayList of ArrayLists in Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I've been working on a larger project, and ran into a problem which I have replicated here in a much simpler fashion. What I'm trying to do is to add an ArrayList of Integers into another ArrayList. The problem is that every ArrayList I add into the larger ArrayList gets updated as if they were all the same.

```
public class RecursionTest {
static ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> test1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

public static void testRecurse(int n) {
    test.add(n);
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        test1.add(test);
    }
    if (n == 0) {   
        for (ArrayList<Integer> a : test1) {
            for (Integer i : a) {
                System.out.print(i + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return;
    }       
    testRecurse(n - 1);     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    testRecurse(10);
}
}
```

The output I get is:

```
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

When it should be:

```
10  
10  9  8  
10  9  8  7  6  
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening here? And perhaps suggest a work around for such a situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the exact same object `test` to the `ArrayList` over and over again. This is why they are all getting modified together.

Everytime you want to add it, you need to create a `new ArrayList<Integer>()` before you add it.

You can try replacing

```
test1.add(test);
```

with

```
test = new ArrayList<Integer>(test);
test1.add(test);
```

This makes a copy of the current test and then adds it to the list.

This would still mean that the `Integer` elements contained in the `ArrayList` would exhibit the same bug, since this is a shallow copy, but since you are not modifying them, it is ok for this case.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I couldn't wrap my head around why test inside test1 was being updated, and assumed that a copy was being made automatically. I modified your solution a bit:   

ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(test);
test1.add(temp);

And that seem to output the correct numbers. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DustinLiang Glad to be of assistance.